# Non-breaking space turns into ‘ă’ under XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, lmodern

Earlier today I noticed the following curious output in a LaTeX file I was editing:

[image: A + ăB = C]

After some investigation I determined that there was a Unicode non-breaking space (U+00A0) between the `+` and the `B`, which somehow turned into an ‘ă’ in the PDF output. Curiously enough, this happens only when the `lmodern` package is loaded, only in math mode, and only when compiled with XeLaTeX — when compiled with pdfLaTeX, there output merely contains an extra-large space between the `+` and the `B`. What causes this behaviour, and why does it only occur under these specific conditions?

Minimal reproducible example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

$A + B = C$

\end{document}
```

(Note that the space in `+ B` is U+00A0 rather than U+0020, which may or may not show up in the rendered post.)

Compile with `xelatex`; `pdflatex` gives different output as discussed above.

Comment: Don't use the lmodern package with xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the tip, I didn’t know that. But why is that such a bad idea?

Comment: I didn't say it is a bad idea, and it is only in part responsable, but normally it is not needed and not using it will avoid the ä for now. But I will have to discuss this with the team.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer!

Comment: Note that when this happens *outside* math mode, it can be fixed with `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't load `lmodern` when running XeLaTeX.

This doesn't really solve the problem, because you get

```
Missing character: There is no   (U+00A0) in font cmr10!
```

but, at least, nothing is printed.

What happens when you run XeLaTeX with `lmodern` is that the text font for family 0 is set to `rm-lmr10`, which has the upper half filled with characters in nonstandard positions. In particular, in slot 0xA0 there is ă and this character is therefore printed.

You can use the math font provided by `lmodern` also in XeLaTeX, but for this you have to extract only the math font definitions in `lmodern.sty`, basically what's after `\ProcessOptions\relax`, so

```
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{lmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{lmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{lmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}

\def\mathsterling{\mathit{\mathchar"70BF}}
```

However, this would still print ă if 0xA0 sneaks in. You can cure the problem by making 0xA0 math active and define it to be `\space`, so in math it gets ignored.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal}{OML}{lmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {OT1}{lmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {bold}  {OML}{lmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {bold}  {OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{normal}{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}  {OT1}{lmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}  {OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}

\def\mathsterling{\mathit{\mathchar"70BF}}

\mathcode"A0="8000
\begingroup\lccode`~="A0 \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\space

\begin{document}

$A + B = C$

\end{document}
```

(I'm not sure that 0xA0 will still be in front of `B` in the code above, fill it in when checking.)

Note 1: I commented out the `largesymbols` definition, because Latin Modern default choice is completely wrong. You may find it useful to also load `fixcmex` to get correctly scaling large operators.

Note 2: this is the same for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: As you know, in LuaLaTeX, you can load `unicode-math` to get Latin Modern Math, or `newcomputermodern`. The OP should be aware that this is simpler and probably will work better.

Comment: @Davislor Possibly, but the OP might have reasons to use the legacy math fonts.

Comment: Possibly. In any case, the option is available.

Comment: But I’m using XeLaTeX, not LuaLaTeX. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @bradrn For safety, I reran the tests with XeLaTeX and it's exactly the same. Sorry for the confusion between Xe and Lua.

Comment: @egreg OK, thanks! Accepted.